# Can the measure restricted from an outer measure extend to a different outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $X$ be a set, and $\rho$ an outer measure on $X$.
Let $\mathcal{M}(\rho)$ be the set of $\rho$-measurable sets.
Then the restriction $\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}$ is a measure on $\mathcal{M}(\rho)$.
By Hahn-Kolmogorov extension theorem, $\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}$ can be extended to an outer measure $\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}^\ast$ on $X$. (As the infimum of the sum of the $\rho$-measures of countably many $\rho$-measurable sets covering a set.) My question is whether the two outer measures $\rho$ and $\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}^\ast$ agree.

I can see that $\rho\leq\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}^\ast$, but I doubt that they are equal in general.

I can show that they are equal if $\rho$ is itself the extension of a (pre-)measure, for example if $\rho$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: $\rho$ and $(\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)})^*$ may not be the same but they generate the same measurable sets and they coincide on $\mathcal{M}(\rho)$.

Comment: @FShrike: Ramiros's example show the what you claim is not correct.

Comment: @Mittens I was thinking of a different phenomenon, about extension of premeasures to measures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $\rho$ and  $\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}^\ast$ are not equal. Here is a counter-example.

Let $X=\Bbb N$ and let $k \in \Bbb N$, $k \geq 2$. Let us define $\rho$ by, for all $A \subseteq X$,
$$  
 \rho(A) = \left \{ \begin{matrix}
 \# A  &  \text{ if }\# A \leq k \\
 k  &     \text{ if } \# A > k 
 \end{matrix}  \right.   
 $$
where $\# A$ is the number of elements in $A$ if $A$ is finite and $\# A$ is $+\infty$ if $A$ is infinite.

It is easy to see that $\rho$ is in fact an outer measure.

Now given any $B \subseteq X$, such that $B \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq X$, then $B$ and $B^c$  are non-empty sets and, at least of them is infinite. Suppose $B$ is infinite.  Let $E = B \cup \{e\}$ where $e \in B^c$. So
$$
 \rho(E)=k < k + 1= \rho(E \cap B) + \rho(E \cap B^c)
 $$
So $B$ is not measurable. Now, suppose $B^c$ is infinite. In a similar way define  $E = B^c \cup \{e\}$ where $e \in B$. Then
$$
 \rho(E)=k < 1 + k= \rho(E \cap B) + \rho(E \cap B^c)
 $$
So $B$ is not measurable. So, in both case,  $B$ is not measurable.
So, we have that $\mathcal{M}(\rho)=\{\emptyset, X \}$ and then the measure $\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}$ is given by  $\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}(\emptyset)=0$ and $\rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}(X)=k$. It follows immediately that
$$  
 \rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}^\ast(A) = \left \{ \begin{matrix}
 0  &  \text{ if } A = \emptyset \\
 k  &     \text{ if } A \neq \emptyset
 \end{matrix}  \right.   
 $$

So $\rho \neq \rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}^\ast$. In fact, given any $e \in X$, we have
$$ \rho(\{e\})=1 < 2 \leqslant k = \rho|_{\mathcal{M}(\rho)}^\ast(\{e\})$$

Comment: (+1) interesting example.